# Twitter api headers with ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services, twitter, http-headers, custom-headers

Mainly to get instant rate limitations (explained here › https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#feature-limiting), in order to call the service the cleanest way possible : on every request, it is possible to get those infos via the `X-FeatureRateLimit-Limit`, `X-FeatureRateLimit-Remaining` and `X-FeatureRateLimit-Reset` sent in the response header.

It is possible to get thse information by calling another endpoint (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/rate_limit_status), but well, at some point seems to consume your quota, wich makes it kind of irrelevant.

My problem is, impossible to get how to read those specific headers…
Might not be that hard, but, if any help by anyone, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [twitter API wrapper](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/error.rb) that handles http header itself:

```
def initialize(message, http_headers)
  @http_headers = Hash[http_headers]
  super message
end

def ratelimit_reset
  Time.at(@http_headers.values_at('x-ratelimit-reset', 'X-RateLimit-Reset').detect{|value| value}.to_i)
end

def ratelimit_limit
  @http_headers.values_at('x-ratelimit-limit', 'X-RateLimit-Limit').detect{|value| value}.to_i
end

def ratelimit_remaining
  @http_headers.values_at('x-ratelimit-remaining', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining').detect{|value| value}.to_i
end
```